# Google Sheets Arrayformula that checks if column A is blank OR if column D is "TRUE" insert message column E

Tags: google-sheets, boolean, array-formulas

My formula: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"","Insert message here"))

The idea is I want to create an Arrayformula that checks if column A is blank OR if column D is "TRUE".  If one of those conditions exists, insert a message in column E.

Column D, TRUE/FALSE column, is populated when I select YES/NO(boolean): No = False, Yes = True.

The formula above is working for column A.  I errored out when I attempted to incorporate column D:

Attempt #1:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),OR(D2:D="TRUE"),"","Insert message here"))

Outcome:
Error message: "Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments."

Attempt #2:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),OR(D2:D="TRUE"),"","Insert message here"))

Outcome:
The formula results were incorrect.

Please enlighten me.

[image: Attempt 1]

[image: Attempt 2]

[image: Formula without column D]

Comment: OR is not supported under AF

Comment: Duly noted. I was taking a stab in the dark. I forgot.  I tried using  (+) for "or" but I was still returning an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ArrayFormula(
 IF((A2:A="")  * (D2:D=FALSE), "",
 IF((A2:A="")  * (D2:D=TRUE),  "E not blank",
 IF((A2:A<>"") * (D2:D=FALSE), "E not blank",
 IF((A2:A<>"") * (D2:D=TRUE),  "E not blank", "")))))
```

[image]

Comment: @lincolntrace can you share a copy of your sheet?